# Americans..please explain the job search process

Tags: usa, employment

I am a non-American living outside of the US.

Several days ago I applied to a position in the US (I am really getting tired with my current job)

On the day I submitted my application, I had an automated email saying: "we will get in touch only if your qualifications meet our needs..."

10 days later, I do get a "touch" otherwise known as a reply, saying "you lack the experience we need, but apply a year later to a position that will be open then"

Does this mean that my qualifications are up to their standards but not my experience, and thus with some more substantive experience (whatever that may mean) I will be eligible to get on board their ship?

Comment: What qualifications were specified in the job advert? It’s pretty easy to ‘tick the box’ for *formal* qualifications (degree-level, for example, or a specific professional qualification) but *experience* can be much more subjective

Comment: The very job category is so new that not even the employer has been able to articulate specific qualifications.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are reading too much into these canned responses. The submission form response lets them simply ignore applicants they don't like, but somewhere up the chain someone actually spent time looking at your resume instead of throwing it into the proverbial waste/recycling/shredding bin right away, but then decided to reject your application for whatever reason, not necessarily the one stated in the email. The system then automatically sent that email. End of story.

The "apply a year later" simply means that if you apply before that, you'll be rejected by the system automatically (perhaps based on your email address).

> Does this mean that my qualifications are up to their standards but not my experience, and thus with some more substantive experience (whatever that may mean) I will be eligible to get on board their ship?

It might mean that, or it might mean something else, e.g. their unwillingness to go through the hassle of arranging a visa for you.

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that you *should not* reapply before a year passes from your rejection. Neither they nor you know what will happen in a year or more - what positions will be available, what additional experience or qualifications you acquire, etc. But within the next year they're pretty certain they have nothing you're qualified for.

Comment: @guest In addition to littleadv's Answer — with which I agree — you should also understand that the company's saying you should _apply_ in a year does not mean that after a year has passed that you'll be offered a job. The company is free to continue searching for possible hires, and in addition could change the company's plans and, for example, even eliminate whatever position the now think "will be open then."

Comment: Well yes, but why would they contact me if they said that they would most likely not even let me know what happened to my candidacy?

Comment: @economics common courtesy? In some US states it may be legally required, as well.

Comment: If it's common courtesy they should'nt have said that they, by default would not contact people unless they had something to offer. Perhaps they have enough time to tailor a lengthy email specifically for me or they have changed their mailing policy in the scope of 10 days?

Comment: I'm keen on this job because...it pays almost 400 thousand a year according to the job posting. It also fits with my lifelong interests.

Comment: I suggest moving on. For a 400K job, you got to ask yourself what do you have to offer that no US citizen in the vicinity has. Then you'll need to write up a very nice cover letter highlighting that next time you submit your resume.